# How to carry data from a form on one file to another using PHP sessions?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, session-variables

I'm trying to make a form that acts as a search engine and returns results. However, the data from the user's entry is either unable to save to a session or the session cannot be passed to another file. Here is the code for the "home" search page and the "Search-Engine" results page.

**Home.php**

```
    <html lang="en-US">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="Search-Engine.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="I'm looking for..." onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('searchbtn').click()">
    <input type="submit" id="searchbtn" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?php session_register(); session_start(); ?>
    <?php $_GET['query'] = $_SESSION['Query']; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Search-Engine.php**

```
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="results">
<?php session_start(); ?>
We could not find: <?php echo $_SESSION['Query']; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you think it maybe because your filename is named with the extension as .html and why are you using session to pass values like that? You could just pass them from the form itself using either post or get?

Comment: Update your Home.html extension to PHP like Home.php for using sessions.

Comment: Even if I move the php session register and rename the file as a php file, it has the same result.

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?> always add at the top

Comment: Add add <?php $_GET['query'] = $_SESSION['Query']; ?> in Search-Engine.php after session_start();

Comment: And why are you doing with GET method, why not POST?

Comment: Running the files with php session start as the first line just returns the code, it does not load the rest of the code...

Comment: No it will not effect your rest of the code. You simply need to use like <?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: Also you can store value in Session in the another page, not in the same page within form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact purpose of using `Sessions` in your form. But you are doing in a wrong way by starting Session in middle of page and using Sessions within the form. You can add value in Sessions in another page after submitting the form.

You can update your files in the below way:

Home.php

```
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Search-Engine.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="query" id="query" placeholder="I'm looking for..." onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('searchbtn').click()">
<input type="submit" id="searchbtn" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Search-Engine.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['Query'] = $_GET['query']; ?>
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="results">
We could not find: <?php echo $_SESSION['Query']; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that the attribute should be name, not id for "query" in the form.